# What are these Riemannian Ghosts?

Tags: fourier-series, graphing-functions, riemann-hypothesis

So for New Year's Eve I'm here with some shining stars straight from the Riemann zeta function!

The following plots show the first 5000 non trivial zeros "winding" around with different frequencies.
More specifically, what is plotted is the set of points

\begin{equation}
(\lambda k\cos(\omega z_k), \lambda k\sin(\omega z_k))_{k=0,\dots,5000}
\end{equation}
where $z_k$ is the imaginary part of the $k$-th zero and $\omega$ and $\lambda$ are parameters.

Essentially this mechanical setup makes the zeros wind up around the origin while also making them spiral out a bit to see the pattern more clearly.

As these plots show, there appear to be some gaps in the spirals, which should correspond to "holes" in the distribution of the zeros. While tinkering with random points instead of the zeros, the patterns don't show up; while experimenting with equally spaced points (a 1-D lattice) of course the patterns show up whenever the "winding frequencies" are rational numbers.

My question is: are these "empty spirals" just ghosts, oddities generated by some sort of aliasing effect or whatnot, or is there something meaningful to have fun with?

Happy New Year!

[image: Riemannian Ghost 1]
[image: Riemannian Ghost 2]
[image: Riemannian Ghost 3]

EDIT: trying to make the observation more quantitative, I tracked the $x$-coordinate of the barycenter of the cloud of points, and discovered that, plotting this coordinate against the frequency one gets "spikes" in a Fourier fashion, corrisponding to frequencies that are the log of primes or prime powers...here's a plot of that as well (using $\log(\omega)$ instead of just $\omega$ as the frequencies)

[image]

Comment: If you try with $\omega = \ln(2)$ you get a really noticeable one-armed "ghost".

Comment: Just in case anyone else is confused by this: The $i$ in the coordinates isn't the imaginary unit but the index $i$ of the zeros.

Comment: Thanks @joriki, I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: If I am right, these spirals reveal "voids" in the spacing of zeroes, at distances that follow an arithmetic progression. By tuning $\omega$, you obtain different Archimedean spirals or for particular values, straight lines. Can you obtain a single straight line (with the $\omega$ of the second picture divided by $8$)?

Comment: Yes, the single straight lines happen at exactly the frequencies that are the log of primes or prime powers.

Comment: To be more precise they are not full straight lines but radiuses.

Comment: What are the three plots?

Comment: @lcv it's explained in the post.

Comment: @marcotrevi : What is $\lambda, \omega$ for the upper, middle, lower plot?

Comment: I don't know, they are still images from an animation I did. But the most interesting values are the frequencies, and they are $\omega = \log(p)$, and $\omega=\log(p^k)$ for $p$ prime.

Comment: I believe this 3blue1brown video is related: https://youtu.be/EK32jo7i5LQ

Comment: @RoyD. Possibly but I don't think so...